# Async Task/Thread in console app

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, console, task

Is it possible to run a `Task` or start a `Thread` asynchron? Short example of what I want to do:

```
public static void Main () {
    // Code

    Task.Run(() => {
        // WebRequest that works asynchron to console
        // I don't need to output results
    });

    // Code

    // Console shouldn't close until Task finished
}
```

Comment: What'S the purpose of this? You are not making anything faster, just slower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call `Task.Wait()` on the result of `Task.Run()`:

```
Task t = Task.Run(() =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("Task is about to exit");
});

Console.WriteLine("Now waiting for the task to exit...");
t.Wait();
```